# Convert Node Stream to Web Stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

How to convert [NodeJS stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) to [Web Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/webstreams.html)

```js
import * as fs from 'node:fs';
const nodeReadable = fs.createReadStream('data.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'});
```

Answer (score 12):

We can use the [`Readable.toWeb()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadabletowebstreamreadable-options), [`Writable.toWeb()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamwritabletowebstreamwritable).

```js
import * as fs from 'node:fs';
import {Readable} from 'node:stream';
const nodeReadable = fs.createReadStream('data.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'});
const webReadableStream = Readable.toWeb(nodeReadable);

const nodeWritable = fs.createWriteStream('data.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'});
const webWritableStream = Writable.toWeb(nodeWritable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking actually for the opposite *(from Web Stream to Stream)*, and for that use `Readable.fromWeb()` and `Writable.fromWeb()` in the same way.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35307860)